# Problem making a virtual host with Apache

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

Once I tried to make a virtual host, and the problem was that if I make another file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` that says

```
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/newsite
ServerName   newsite
...
```

Then save it, restart Apache, and appending `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.0.1 newsite
```

I get the page that corresponds the DocumentRoot from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

That time I left it unsolved. Now I want to do it once again and I get the same problem. Despite the fact that I use different version of Linux distro. I feel like I'm doomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you enable the site using the *a2ensite* command? The */etc/apache2/sites-available* directory lists those that you have setup but it needs to be in */etc/apache2/sites-enabled* to be picked up when you next reload the apache2 configuration.

Comment: damn, that was easy! I don know why i didnt ever faced this command reading dozens of how to's and examples. Thank you so much